# Clear infringement of originality and sources for inclined beds supported by prior art and website

Tags: us20150250324

In reference to the patent: [US20150250324](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150250324)

I have spent 21 years of my life promoting inclined sleeping as Inclined Bed Therapy, following a breakthrough in how gravity drives circulation. I applied for a patent for an inclined bed, through the UK Office which predates any of these claims. The patent was turned down. Despite this, this discovery was far too important to be stopped by a patent refusal, so I have continued to conduct self funded research into medical conditions, encouraging people to incline their own beds on blocks, books, bricks etc and to modify their own beds to incorporate and inclined sleeping surface. My website, http://inclinedbedtherapy.com where the author of this and two other patents has lifted my research, doctored it in the guise of supporting their claims of the origin of this work has been brought to my attention by several sources. I have written to the company for which these patent applications have been constructed, asking for an explanation for what is nothing short of an attempt to steal my many years of hard work and medical research.
No response has been received? In 1997 I won a gold award for this box design at the London International Inventions fair, which was also reported in press. I have the supporting cuttings and the original sales brochure, which I will gladly provide to disprove the claims in these patents.
Furthermore, my research revealed the earliest inclined beds came from Egyptian tombs and there are other examples in paintings, drawings and at least one photographic example of a more recent example from Egypt.

The similarities of the text relates to how cows and sheep sleep, how an inclined bed eliminates migraines and how it has helped with may other conditions that I, and many others have provided evidence for over 21 years.

It is my intention to start producing the inclined beds as a new company, so I hope you can help to resolve these issues and rest assured that I can prove everything I have stated here.

Kind regards

Andrew K Fletcher

Comment: Dear Andrew if your intention is to oppose the application this forum can help you in finding prior arts, but its unclear from your post what you are looking for. could you reframe question in Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

You can send third party observations to the USPTO to tell them about your evidence. But there is another issue I want to bring to your attention:

A patent on this matter has already been granted in Europe ( https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=EP&NR=2915455B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=1&date=20160907&DB=&locale=# ). The opposition time for a european patent is 9 months after the grant and its running, so if you want to do anything against the european patent before it gets even more costly (after the 9 months) you might want to hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Claim 1 of this application specifically refers to a design where there is an inner frame that adjusts in inclination with respect to a fixed outer frame. Your website shows an arrangement where blocks are added under the headboard legs. Do you have specific prior art for the arrangement as described in he cited applications claims?  If not the this may be patentable. That said, adjustable beds where the upper portion of the mattress can be inclined (along with other sections) have been on the market for many years and may be considered prior art.

Comment: He is describing a tilt table, which is used to incline or decline a person, hinged in the centre, nothing new here, other than his frame rests horizontally as opposed to vertically for a tilt frame.  There are also beds, particularly hospital beds that are hinged in the centre to cause a bed to be inclined or in the Trendelenburgh position, which is sloping down from head to toe. I have my original patent application which was rejected together with a printed brochure showing an inclined box framed bed, which I sold and exhibited at the London Int Inv Fair 1997

Comment: Here is a typical tilting bed frame http://www.aliexpress.com/item/FIR-Far-Infrared-Jade-Therapy-Massage-Bed-Spinal-Traction-Decompression-Table-with-Back-Tilt-and-Germanium/1559845498.html

Comment: @AndrewKFletcher  Excellent points. You should put them in an answer.